# Extract capital letters from word boundary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract capitalized text between `"at"` and `"on"`.

```
s = 'visit at AIRTEL on some day'
import re
re.findall('(?<=at).[A-Z]+.(?=on)', s)
```

This returns the expected word correctly.

But fails in other cases for e.g.

```
s = 'visit at AIRTEL.IN on some day'
```

The Capital letters may contain one or more special characters. Though the expected string will be always between the word boundaries of `'at'` and `'on'`.

Comment: Simply include all special characters you want to permit in the character set?

Comment: You need to account for dot and enhance your character set to `[A-Z.]+`

Comment: After checking the data, I can see special chars like * and space as well.

Comment: In that case you can use `.+?` That will capture anything between `at` and the very next `on`

Comment: *"The Capital letters may contain one or more special characters."* You need to know all those special characters to form an exhaustive regex pattern

Comment: @CinCout the data is too big to check. Anything other than A-Za-z is special character in this case.

Comment: @CinCout: I only suggested dot when OP said, he is seeing special characters and spaces in the text. Else he needs to use a precise character set that I already said above.

Comment: @shantanuo: I'll suggest you capture everything using `.+?` and then in next step remove anything that isn't capital letter if that works for you.

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to define what is NOT allowed? For instance, perhaps you want something between two spaces which is not a small letter? Are numbers allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`at\b([^a-z]*)\bon`

Since you said you need to capture everything other than small case letters, hence everything other than `A-Z` and `a-z` becomes *special characters* in this case. I recommend using a negative character set. This regex captures everything between `at` and `on` that is not having small letters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bONGbe/2)